# Keeping legacy Carbon code alive

Tags: cocoa, 64-bit, osx-snow-leopard, macos-carbon

Apple has killed Carbon for 64 bit applications.  I've got a pile of legacy code that targets carbon UI widgets that I'd like to keep alive for a while.   Most of it is in the form of plugins and bundles that will have to go 64-bit in sync with their host platform.

The choice that Apple seems to be assuming is to throw all the legacy code away
and rewrite using Cocoa.  It's not going to happen in the short run, if only because 
the same legacy code is tied to a PC binding as well.

I'm considering 3 Options

(1) Dive into cocoa, create a compatibility package that supports the small subset
of carbon that I actually need.

(2) use Cocoatron as the new target.  In the short run bridge carbon-to-cocotron, and maybe in the longer run convert to cocoatron native for both mac and pc.  (ref: http://cocotron.org/)

(3) use QT as the new target. See option (2). (ref: http://qt.nokia.com/)

What I would really prefer is a fourth option, such as a bootleg copy of the 64 bit
Carbon beta that Apple killed, or a compatibility package explicitly intended just
to emulate carbon.

Comment: To give an answer that's not completely general, we need more detail.  What does the legacy code do?  What type of application is it?  Is there a link where we could learn more?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you choose option 1. Creating a Cocoa UI wrapper for your code will likely not be as complex as you think. A common way to create a cross-platform app is to create the bulk of the app in cross-platform C++ and use Cocoa/Objective-C++ for the Mac UI and one of the Windows APIs for the Windows UI.

This option also has the advantage that it is fully supported by Apple and the APIs are stable and mature.

Cocotron is a nice idea but as of now it's not mature enough (in my opinion) to provide a robust cross-platform solution. I know there are successes with it but the sample size is small.

Qt is an option. However, it suffers from a very un-Mac-like UI. Using a Qt app on the Mac always feels like a quick port rather than a native app, and this is unlikely to ever change.

The "bootleg Carbon runtime" is just a fantasy, there is simply no way to get that working reliably and absolutely no chance to distribute it. You will need to find another way.